# Where do i add keyboard controls to a sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

When i try to run this simple game. it says:

```
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50 + M ,337 + N))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'M' referenced before assignment
```

this is from the bellow code:

```
import pygame
import os, sys
import itertools
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

cloud_background = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp')
brick_tile = pygame.image.load('brick_tile.png')
plumbers = pygame.image.load('Mario_sideways_sprite_2xL.png')

pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1

def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(cloud_background,(0,0))
    brick_width, brick_height = brick_tile.get_width(), brick_tile.get_height()
    for x,y in itertools.product(range(0,640,brick_width),
                                 range(390,480,brick_height)):
        # print(x,y)
        screen.blit(brick_tile, (x,y))


def show_sprites():
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50 + M ,337 + N))
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        M = 1
        N = 0

while running:
    setup_background()
    show_sprites()
    move()
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

But when i add the variable above "screen.blit" so it looks like this:

```
def show_sprites():
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        M = 1
        N = 0
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50 + M ,337 + N))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\GAMEZ_PYGAME\gamez.py", line 36, in <module>
    show_sprites()
  File "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\GAMEZ_PYGAME\gamez.py", line 28, in show_sprites
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
NameError: global name 'event' is not defined
```

What do i have to add/ change to get these simple controls to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have two problems. Python sees the first one and stops with an exception.

In :

```
def show_sprites():
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50 + M ,337 + N))
    .......
```

M and N still don't exist when called.
Try for example:

```
def show_sprites():
    print M, N
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50 + M ,337 + N))
    .......
```

In

```
def show_sprites():
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
```

neither `event` has been defined.

You should check a tutorial about function arguments/parameters and local variables.

your function should looks like this (for example):

```
def show_sprites(M, N, event):
```

or most likely:

```
def show_sprites(event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        M = 1
        N = 0
    else:
        M = 0  # ? up to you
        N = 0  # ?
    screen.blit(plumbers,(50 + M ,337 + N))
```

with:

```
while running:
    setup_background()
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
    show_sprites(event)
    move()
```

Finally, this code will send all kind of events to your function so you should filter them:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    sys.exit()
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    show_sprites(event)
    move()
```

check [this](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/12/16/pygame-tutorial-5-pixels/) for example

Comment: I tried you suggestion and i got the error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\GAMEZ_PYGAME\gamez.py", line 41, in <module>
    show_sprites(event)
  File "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\GAMEZ_PYGAME\gamez.py", line 28, in show_sprites
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'key'
@joaquin

Comment: what does it mean that  "event object has no attribute key  @joaquin